# Controlling DPI of plot in R

Tags: r, plot, tiff, dpi

Need to make a plot in R, where i have to control the DPI size of the figure to produce. I have to use either EPS of TIF format. I have no idea, how to control this in R. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I have created a bit of sample code.

```
x = seq(1,10,0.1)
y = seq(1,10,0.1)

plot(x,y, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "orange", xlab = "X-label", ylab = "Y-Label")
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to save high-resolution plot in tiff format

```
x = seq(1,10,0.1)
y = seq(1,10,0.1)
    
tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=5, height=5, res=300)
plot(x,y, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "orange", xlab = "X-label", ylab = "Y-Label")              
dev.off()
```

Here, `res` is equivalent to DPI. You can play with the `width` and `height` of the image which are in inches.